# Use Script and XML Feed to pause Adgroups in Google Adwords

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I'm trying to do a script which pauses an adgroup based in the field AVAILABILITY in a XML (a Google Merchant XML).

I have a merchant XML, and want to use the ID (the id is algo used in the adgroup name) and AVAILABILITY (In Stock, Out of Stock, Preorder) from the XML to pause Adgroups in my campaign.

I tried to modify an example, [I had found here](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Advanced-Features/Adwords-script-for-enabling-and-pausing-campaigns-based-on/td-p/527633#.WKWa2cdZVOw.google_plusone_share), using adgroups in place of campaigns, but I think the error is when the script try to read the XML.
In the lines bellow lines I receive the error: "TypeError: Cannot call method "getValue" of null. (line 16)"

```
var id = entries[i].getChild('g:id').getValue();
var availability = entries[i].getChild('g:availability').getValue();
```

**My XML is like this:**

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>
                <![CDATA[ Far Cry 4: Overrun ]]>
            </title>
            <link>https://www.nuuvem.com/item/far-cry-4-overrun</link>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[
Neste novo conteúdo para Far Cry 4, enquanto a guerra sem trégua por Kyrat continua, os jogadores assumirão o papel dos Rakshasa e do Caminho Dourado para manter locais que dão pontos no mapa da batalha.
]]>
            </description>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price currency="BRL">8.99</g:price>
            <g:image_link> http://dskhvldhwok3h.cloudfront.net/image/upload/t_boxshot_big/v1/products/557dbcb269702d0a9c490801/boxshots/ynhjodwlnmur0crkiaxp.jpg </g:image_link>
            <g:product_type>
                <![CDATA[ Ação ]]>
            </g:product_type>
            <g:google_product_category>Software > Video Game Software > Computer Games</g:google_product_category>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:identifier_exists>FALSE</g:identifier_exists>
            <g:id>2668</g:id>
        </item>
```

**My script now looks like this:**

```
function main() {
    // Load an XML file:
    var xmlURL = "XML URL HERE";
    var xmlFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(xmlURL);
    // Parse the XML file:
    var document = XmlService.parse(xmlFile);
    var root = document.getRootElement();
    // Go through all children of <deepdive_pages>:
    var entries = document.getRootElement().getChildren();
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        //for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var id = entries[i].getChild('g:id').getValue();
        var availability = entries[i].getChild('g:availability').getValue();
        // If company_root_id has 0 jobs 
        if (availability == "out of stock") {
            var adGroupIterator = AdWordsApp.adGroups().withCondition('Name CONTAINS "| ' + id + ' |"').get(); // Find all campaigns with the company name
            while (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) { // Go over all campaings with company id in the name
                var adgroup = adGroupIterator.next();
                if (adgroup.isEnabled()) { // If campaign is enables, pause it
                    adgroup.pause();
                    Logger.log("adgroup " + adgroup.getName() + " was paused.");
                }
            }
        }
        // If company_root_id has MORE than 0 jobs 
        else {
            var adGroupIterator = AdWordsApp.adGroups().withCondition('Name CONTAINS "| ' + id + ' |"').get(); // Find all campaigns with the company name
            while (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) { // Go over all campaings with company id in the name
                var adgroup = adGroupIterator.next();
                if (adgroup.isPaused()) { // If campaign is paused, enable it
                    adgroup.enable();
                    Logger.log("adgroup " + adgroup.getName() + " was enabled.");
                }
            }
        } // End If Else
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Calin in this post: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Advanced-Features/Script-to-pause-Adggroups-based-in-information-from-a-Merchant/m-p/1024590#

I solved my problem.

To read the XML correctly, I used:

```
// Load an XML file:
 var xmlURL = "XML_MERCHANT_URL_HERE";
 var xmlFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(xmlURL);

 // Parse the XML file:
 var document = XmlService.parse(xmlFile);
 var ns = XmlService.getNamespace("http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");   
 var rss = document.getRootElement().getChildren(); //root element is <rss>; it's children are actually only one, <channel>
 var entries = rss[0].getChildren('item'); //getting all 'item' children of the first rss element, <channel>

 // Go through all children of <deepdive_pages>:
 Logger.log(entries.length);

 for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

 var id = entries[i].getChild('id',ns).getText();

 var availability = entries[i].getChild('availability',ns).getText();

//Logger.log("ID: "+id+", Availability: "+availability);
```

Before I did'nt declared the XML namespace and I was using `getchild`, but in this case I need to use `getChildren`.